# How to retrieve attempted $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] from URL when no authentication is required

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, http-authentication

Normally when a publicly-accessible directory requires basic HTTP authentication, the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` and/or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` (or `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, etc) will be set and accessible to PHP once a valid username/password combination have been provided to the server.

For example, if `http://www.example.com/members` requires basic authentication, and a user successfully authenticates using the credentials `myusername` and `mypassword` by manually typing `http://myusername:mypassword@www.example.com/members` into their browser, the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` would be something like:

```
Basic bXl1c2VybmFtZTpteXBhc3N3b3Jk
```

... and the value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` would simply be:

```
myusername
```

However if authentication is not required in the same directory, but the URL is still visited with the username/password inside of it, the values of the username/password don't seem to be set anywhere (running PHP 5.3.10 as CGI/FastCGI on Apache/2.2.22).

**From within PHP (and/or `.htaccess` if necessary), *when no authentication is required*, is there a way to retrieve the values of the username (and/or password) that have been provided by a visitor who manually added them to the URL?**

Comment: It might not be forwarded to PHP by Apache if it's not required by the 401 header

Comment: I just made a test page and `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` are both set in the `$_SERVER` array, even when there's no authentication required.

Comment: @Phil Hmm... That makes me wonder if this particular setup I'm working with is missing an Apache module or something. And if that's the case, which one would it be? Also, if you send unnecessary user/pass credentials will `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` contain those values that were sent?

Comment: @Phil I made also a test page and those values don't seem to be anywhere. Using FastCGI here, PHP 5.4.41. What Server API and PHP version are you using? OP could add that information as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR; As far as I can see that information is never sent to server so I claim it's not possible.

The way http authentication works if you have it set is that server sends a request for user/pass if it's not already set, and browser then adds that information in encoded form to a `Authorization` header and sends it to the server along with the request.

As specified in RFC 2617, describing Basic and Digest authentication mechanisms For basic authentication, server sends `HTTP 401 Not Authorized` status and `WWW-Authenticate` header fields to request this information. ([RFC 2617, Access Authentication Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-1.2))

With tests one can see that if authentication is never configured on the server to be required, server won't request authentication information from browser, and browser won't add user/pass information into the request. RFC does not mandate browser (user agent) to not pass that information, but says instead

> A user agent that wishes to authenticate itself with an origin
> server--usually, but not necessarily, after receiving a 401
> (Unauthorized)--MAY do so by including an Authorization header field
> with the request.

In practice, if you watch the sent headers you can see that if this information is requested by the server, it's sent in encoded form using `Authorization` header like specified by the RFC. However, if you're not using any authentication the request you send just doesn't seem to contain that information in any form. I've confirmed this with IE, Firefox and Chrome browsers myself.

---

If you want to test this yourself for your setup, this can be done for example using netcat like this:

First, run netcat on your server:

```
nc -l 8888
```

Then issue a request from your browser to `http://testvalue:testvalue@yourdomain:8888/`

As a result, observe from netcat output all the information that get sent to server, something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: yourdomain:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

There is no information about user or password anywhere. I claim that unless the server requests it, it won't be there.

Answer (score 3):

The addition of user and password in a url using http(s)://user:pass@site.com has been disabled by at least Internet Explorer for several years now, as far as i know.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489

So I am not sure if what you are trying to reach is even usefull. I think the browsers dont even pass that part of the url on anymore.

Comment: Other browsers haven't disabled it, but it is true that IE has.